# Add WebJob to Azure App Service - permission issue

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, webjob

My client has Azure subscription and has App Service inside. My Azure account is added to this App Service as owner. Now I need to add WebJob to this App Service. I have added WebJob project to Visual Studio solution, linked with Website project and try to publish (under my azure account). WebJob is deployed, but schedule can't be configured, I get an error:

> Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: Response
>   status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduled WebJobs use Azure Scheduler behind the scene to trigger the webjob. So, I think you need to have the rights to create an Azure scheduler too to make it working.

Another solution is to use the internal Kudu webjob scheduler, as explained in this post: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/

Comment: where can I set rights to create an Azure scheduler on Azure portal?

Comment: I think it may be better if you are added as an owner of the resource group the app service is in.  That 'should' allow you to add scheduler resources to that group.  Permissions can be added at Subscription level, resource group level or resource level ... right now it sounds like you may be set at the resource level.  For more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/